# Symbolic Integration of Gaussian in SymPy

Tags: sympy

I am trying to integrate a function of the form *cos(x)*exp(-x²)* in SymPy, but I am getting no result. The result would involve some sort of error-function. If I try to integrate just a gaussian (for example with `integrate(exp(-x**2), x)`), I get an output in its error-function form. Is there any tricks so SymPy can handle more advanced functions?

Comment: I probably can't answer your question. What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: The integral comes from a variation of parameters, but what I really want to do is evaluate the integral at specific points.

Comment: If you would settle for that then you could consider asking another question about optimal ways of approximating that function. (You must have thought of that.)

Comment: Yes , I have tried to approximate the function using a Taylor-series. There are two issues with that, one is that the convergence rate for the series seems to be low, and second that SymPy using a long time to evaluate the integral consisting of terms cos(x) and polynomials. Perhaps the speed of integration is an issue in general in SymPy?

Comment: This seems to be outside the scope of this forum. Accordingly I asked about it on meta and received this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286977/where-should-one-post-questions-about-numerical-analysis/286978#286978. Please let us know if you don't receive useful answers there.